# Gradients in Keras loss function with RNNs

Tags: tensorflow, keras, loss-function

I have a simple test LSTM model:

```
inputs = Input(shape=(k, m))
layer1 = LSTM(128, activation='relu', return_sequences=True)(inputs)
layer2 = LSTM(128, activation='relu')(layer1)
predictions = Dense(1, activation='linear')(layer2)
model = Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=predictions)
```

and a custom loss function that uses output gradients wrt inputs:

```
def custom_loss(model, input_tensor):
    def loss(y_true, y_pred):
        grads = K.gradients(model.output, model.input)[0] 
        loss_f = losses.mean_squared_error(y_true, y_pred) + K.exp(-K.sum(grads))
        return loss_f

return loss
```

Model training fails with error "Second-order gradient for while loops not supported":

```
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss=custom_loss(model_reg, inputs_reg), metrics=['mean_absolute_error'])
model_reg.fit(x_train, y_train, batch_size=32, epochs=20, verbose=1, validation_data=(x_val, y_val)) 

-----
....
      159 
      160   if op_ctxt.grad_state:
-->   161     raise TypeError("Second-order gradient for while loops not supported.")
      162 
      163   if isinstance(grad, ops.Tensor):

TypeError: Second-order gradient for while loops not supported.
```

Why TF tries to compute second-order gradients here? It should be just first order.

The same loss function works well for non-RNN models.

Comment: You are computing gradients in `grads` and add a term involving them to the loss function. Since gradient descent requires the gradient of the loss, this will try to compute the gradient of the gradients, i.e. second-order gradients.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting Unroll property helped to resolve the issue:

```
layer1 = LSTM(128, activation='relu', return_sequences=True, unroll=True)(inputs)
layer2 = LSTM(128, activation='relu', unroll=True)(layer1)
```